# I sent XMR to an address and it has not turned up?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I sent XMR from my GUI wallet, and for some reason it has not turned up at the destination.
The address in the transaction details is different than the address that I tried to send to.
Does this mean it has gone to the wrong location?
There is a orange circle next to the "sent" transaction. Does this mean it hasnt arrived?
How do i get these funds back?